# Capture a var from a function in a different ViewController | Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I am making a horoscope app and in the main view controller you can click a series of buttons to pull up a pop up screen which would display their horoscope.

I have a major function buttonLayout() that makes all the buttons for my ViewController and sets their images.

After you click on a button I want it to bring up a popUp WITH THAT SAME BUTTON THAT THEY CLICKED ON IN THE MAIN VIEWCONTROLLER

The part I capitalized is what I cannot figure out how to do.

[image: main ViewController]

[image: clicking a button]

[image: the popUp view controller where I want the corresponding button to be displayed]

This is my code for the ViewController:
    //  ViewController.swift
    //  Zodiacv2

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel! 
@IBOutlet weak var subHeaderLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    headerLayout()
    buttonLayout()
}

func headerLayout() {
    headerLabel.text = header
    subHeaderLabel.text = subHeader
}

func buttonLayout() {
    for index in 0..<9 {
        var yPos = 195
        var xPos = (105 * index) + 50
        if (xPos >= 300) {
            yPos += 135
            xPos -= 315
        }
        if (xPos >= 300) {
            yPos += 135
            xPos -= 315
        }
        let button = UIButton()
        let buttonImage = UIImage(named: sign[index])
        button.setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: 105, height: 130)
        button.tag = 5
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
}

func buttonClicked() {
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopUp") as! PopUpViewController
    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

}

This is my code for my popUp View Controller:

```
//  PopUpViewController.swift
//  Zodiacv2
import UIKit

class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var headerlabelPop: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.showAnimate()
    self.headerlabelPop.text = subHeader
}

func showButton() {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "PopUp", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main") as! ViewController

}

func showAnimate() {
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3,y: 1.3)
    self.view.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0,y: 1.0)
    });
}

@IBAction func closePopUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
    removeAnimate()
}

func removeAnimate() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3,y: 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: {(finished : Bool) in
        if (finished) {
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    });
}
```

}

In the showButton function I want to access either the index so I can say sign[index] or the UIButton image from the buttonLayout() function.

Comment: `button.tag = 5` => `button.tag = index`. Add a var to the seconds VC, and before presenting it, show it. Also, why do you use ChildVC? From your screenshots, a push may be what you really want to do.

Comment: Im kinda confused with the .tag property. If I put this line of code in does this mean that my index will be 5 every time?  @Larme

Comment: No, it will be 0, 1, etc. The question is why putting 5 each times? What's the goal? If you put the index as the tag, then you can easily retrieve the index.

Comment: Do you really need to pass a button into new view controller, not just an image or image name?

Comment: @Larme I see what you are saying! That worked!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just inject the value of the button to the new view controller.
(This is code from the code you shared)

```
func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopUp") as! PopUpViewController
    popOverVC.characteristic = sign[sender.tag]
    self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
    popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

But I would change the way you are presenting the buttons.
It would be better to use just a `UICollectionView` and then handle the tap of each Cell (using `UICollectionViewDelegate`).

Comment: what does the .characteristic property doing? Or I should ask, do I need to make a variable for the .characteristic property because when I put this code in XCode I am getting an error saying PopUpViewController has no member characteristic.

Comment: yes, you need to create one in the popUpViewController. There you will have set the value of the button that was pressed in order to present that view.